# Querying two MongoDB collections with PHP, first returns correct result, but second is empty

Tags: php, mongodb

I run two MongoDB queries from PHP, one on a first collection (named "products"), second on another collection (named stats).

Some datas of the two collections :

```
{
"_id" : "20711122",
"labels_hierarchy" : [ 
    "en:pgi"
],
"languages_hierarchy" : [ 
    "en:french"
],
"labels_prev_hierarchy" : [ 
    "en:pgi"
],
"languages" : {
    "en:french" : 5
},
"countries_tags" : [ 
    "en:france"
],
"purchase_places_debug_tags" : [],
"photographers_tags" : [ 
    "tacite"
]
}
```

Other collection :

```
{
"_id" : "7613035010550",
"purchases" : [ 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-15T14:15:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.729604,
            "lat" : 1.416017
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 2.31
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T16:23:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.722862,
            "lat" : 1.415837
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 6,
        "price" : 12
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T18:32:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 46.307353,
            "lat" : 3.28937
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 2,
        "price" : 5
    }
],
"rates" : [ 
    {
        "value" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 2
    }
]
}
```

As u see, collections are different but the "_id" key...

When i run a query on the first collection (products), everything is ok, but the second with the same "_key" returns empty results, here's the trace of the two queries (made with executeQuery() of MongoDB::Driver) :

```
<pre><code>Interrogation de la collection : stats
Avec le filtre :
{"id":"7613035010550"}
<pre><code>Interrogation de la collection : products
Avec le filtre :
{"id":"7613035010550"}
Results :
{"ean":"7613035010550","title":"Eau Min\u00e9rale Naturelle","image":"https:\/\/static.openfoodfacts.org\/images\/products\/761\/303\/501\/0550\/front_fr.11.400.jpg","brands":"Vittel","categories":["Boissons","Eaux","Eaux min\u00e9rales","Eaux min\u00e9rales naturelles","Boissons non sucr\u00e9es"],"quantity":"1.5 l."}
```

As u can see, only the first query returns results, not the second...

Any idea of this curious behaviour ?

Thx 4 help,

JL

Answer (score 0):

I'm just stupid or tired...
Second query was execute with "id" key but not "_id" key... So, always returns empty results...

Just take another 4 shots coffee and next...

JL